# What mean the parameters minBufferTime and timeShiftBufferDepth?

Tags: video-streaming, audio-streaming, mpeg-dash

I found in a Media Presentation Description these parameters, but I don't know what it's for.

I am debugging a video-streaming.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

These attributes are described in [ISO/IEC 23009-1:2014](https://www.iso.org/standard/65274.html), which specified the Media Presentation Description (MPD).

`@minBufferTime` is mandatory and described as:

> specifies a common duration used in the definition of the
>   Representation data rate (see @bandwidth attribute in
>   5.3.5.2).

The reference to the `@bandwidth` attribute is:

> a client can be assured of having enough data for continuous playout providing playout begins after @minBufferTime * @bandwidth bits have been received (i.e. at time @minBufferTime after the first bit is received).

---

`@timeShiftBufferDepth` is optional and described as:

> specifies the duration of the smallest time shifting buffer
>   for any Representation in the MPD that is guaranteed to
>   be available for a Media Presentation with type
>   'dynamic'. When not present, the value is infinite. This
>   value of the attribute is undefined if the type attribute is
>   equal to ‘static’.

This means it specifies how long segments are guaranteed to be stored on the server-side after being published.